# viewExpiredException JSF

Tags: java, session, jsf, viewexpiredexception

To handle viewExpiredException in JSF, I coded

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

in `web.xml`.

In `error.html` I have redirected to original login page. But the problem is session scoped bean were not cleared out even session expired. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The login page is likely been requested from the browser cache. Disable it by creating a `Filter` which is tied to the `FacesServlet` and has basically the following lines in the `doFilter()` method, so that you don't need to repeat it over all pages which you'd like to prevent from being cached.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

Comment: If I use Facelets and have a fixed layout, is there any difference setting it in the header or in a filter?

Comment: @Rin: No, there's absolutely no difference. You only need to keep in mind that the HTTP response headers have always precedence over the ones set in meta. So if the server has set some defaults in the HTTP response header, then they will override the ones which you set in meta. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsfprimefaces-application/10305799#10305799

Comment: Sorry, forgot to thank you. :) It was very enlightening;