# The JSF page ins't redirecting using by Filter interface

Tags: jsf, redirect, servlet-filters

I am developing jsf login and logout smaller web app.I see some problems.My logout method don't removed session and not working redirecting to login page.I have asked from stackoverflow.com.The Matt user answered Filter class to me.Then I researching Filter and page cache according Matt.I used to Filter's doFilter() method, in web.xml file  etc..

Here is my code:

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {


@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    UserController userController = (UserController) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");


    if (userController == null || !userController.isLoggedIn()) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsf");
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
```

}

And logout()

```
    public String logout() {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = context.getExternalContext();
    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest();
    request.getSession(false).invalidate();
    return "logout";
}
```

And web.xml configuration:

```
<filter>
     <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.bis.logic.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

After logging I rendering home page.

```
<body>
 <!-- 
 #{ session.invalidate(); 
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsf");
  } -->
 <h:panelGrid rendered="#{userController.isLoggedIn()}">

 Hello Mr . #{userController.user.name}

<br />
<h:form>
    <p align="right">
          <h:commandLink action="#{userController.logout()}"value="Logout" />
    </p>
</h:form>
</h:panelGrid>
</body>
```

My userController managedBean class:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userController")
```

@SessionScoped
public class UserController {

```
private User user;

public UserController() {
    user = new User();
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public static void addErrorMessage(String msg) {
    FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
            msg, msg);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMsg);
}

public String authenticate() {

    if (user.getName().equals("admin") && user.getPassword().equals("")) {
        return "success";
    } else
        addErrorMessage(String
                .format("Username and Password didn't match !!!"));
    return "fail";

}
```

The page navigation xml:

```
    <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/home.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>fail</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/home.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{userController.logout()}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: THIS IS A ERROR PAGE PICTURE

 http://i.stack.imgur.com/YbkIV.png

Answer (score 3):

Your filter is running in an infinite redirect loop. The request on `login.jsf` will also invoke the filter. If the user is still not logged in, then it will redirect back to `login.jsf` which will in turn invoke the filter again, etcetera.

There are basically 2 ways to fix this:

1. Make sure that `login.jsf` is not covered by the URL pattern of the filter. Collect all secured pages (expect of `login.jsf`!) in a separate folder like `/app`, `/secured`, `/pages`, etc and map the filter on that URL pattern instead, e.g. `/app/*`.
2. Add an extra check which determines if the request is already requesting the login page and if so, then don't redirect to it again.

   ```
   String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsf";

   boolean loggedIn = userController != null && userController.isLoggedIn();
   boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL);

   if (loggedIn || loginRequest) {
       chain.doFilter(request, response);
   } else {
       response.sendRedirect(loginURL);
   }
   ```

Comment: ![Don't redirect to login page after logout.In this image means that browser back button is clicked after logout.Basically checking redirecting login page][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VNbEf.png

Comment: You need to tell the browser to not cache the pages. See for a concrete example also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsfprimefaces-application/10305799#10305799 You could even do the job in the filter which you already have there.

Comment: I used CacheControllPhaseListenner class.public class

Comment: Mr.BalusC I change to add code to up post's Filter class ? Or write to new NoCacheFilter class ?