# JSF server side validation on browser back button hit

Tags: validation, jsf, back-button

Is there any way to differentiate a browser back button request and a submit request in the listener?

Is there a way to do server side validation when a user hits browser back button & forward button consecutively?

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there any way to differentiate a browser back button request and a submit request in the listener?*

Not in the server side. The back button request is namely not necessarily been sent to the server, but instead requested on the browser's cache.

---

> *Is there a way to do server side validation when a user hits browser back button & forward button consecutively?*

Just tell the browser to not cache the page at all. This way it will guarantee send a full request to the server side where all the associated code will be invoked.

You can find a kickoff example of such a filter in this answer: [Avoid back button on JSF web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsfprimefaces-application/10305799#10305799).