# restricting user to go back after logout not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, httpresponse, logout, restriction

I have created webapplication using JSF 2.0 where I want to restrict user to go back after logout.

For solution I looked at [Great BalusC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-going-back-to-the-previous-secured-page-after-logout) and tried something else, however it is not working.

What I tried is as below.

```
<h:commandLink value="logout" action="#{bean.makeMeLogut()}" />
```

in bean I have

```
public void makeMeLogut() {
    try {
        // get response from JSF itself instead of coming from filter.
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("isLoggedIn", "false");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        hsr.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        hsr.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        hsr.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("can't logut...");
    }
}
```

As per BalusC answer, I need to create filter, however I thought to use JSF response and set header into it. However it is not working.

**Any idea where I am going wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting those headers on the response of the restricted page itself, but you're only setting those headers on the response of the logout action. So the restriced page itself is still in the browser cache, only the logout action is not in the browser cache. However, the back button does not go to the logout action, it goes to the restricted page (which is thus still served up from the browser cache).

You really need a filter on all requests to those restriced pages, exactly as outlined in the answer you found.

#### See also:

- [Avoid back button on JSF web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsfprimefaces-application)
- [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, manipulating the session map right before invalidate makes no sense. The session invalidation would implicitly already clear out the entire map (as it basically refers to the attributes of the session). Just remove the line wherein you manpulate the session map.

Also the catch on `IOException` which does only a stdout is extremely poor. Remove the whole `try-catch` and add `throws IOException` to the method. The container will handle it with an error page.

Comment: Very much Thank You Sir, it works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome for me, but unfortunately on Safari in iPad mini, it doesnt.. :( I cant get it to work on Safari. Any idea do You maybe have ?