# Logout functionality not working properly

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My bean class code is:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
ExternalContext ec = context.getExternalContext(); 
final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest(); 
request.getSession(false).invalidate();
return "logout";
```

Here my problem is whenever user successfully login and do some work in transaction page after he click on logout button, logout will work but when user click back button on browser window it opens the user transaction page.

Comment: not jsf web page back button browserpage back button

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your browser takes data from cache. Try Balusc [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsf-web-application). Of course you may need to implement in your filter class, abstract methods from `filter` interface, I mean methods `init` and `destroy`.