# JSF Redirect to Login page after session expired throws ViewExpiredException

Tags: jsf-2, servlet-filters

I'm working on project that uses:Java 7, Glassfish 4, JSF 2.2, Primefaces 5...
I'm handling authentication using jdbcRealm and HttpServletRequest#login():

I've set a NoCacheFilter as per BalusC's awnser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsf-web-application/10305799#10305799).

And have set ViewExpiredException to redirect to login page in web.xml

Whenever a session expire the user should be redirected to the login page to authenticate again, but getting a this exception:

```
Warning:   Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/index.xhtml - View /index.xhtml could not be restored.
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:210)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.forwardToLoginPage(FormAuthenticator.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:264)
at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1524)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:585)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:702)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Warning:   Unexpected error forwarding or redirecting to login page
javax.servlet.ServletException: viewId:/index.xhtml - View /index.xhtml could not be restored.
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.forwardToLoginPage(FormAuthenticator.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:264)
at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1524)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:585)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:702)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/index.xhtml - View /index.xhtml could not be restored.
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:210)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
... 35 more
```

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
   <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
      <param-value>Development</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
      <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <session-config>
      <session-timeout>
           1
      </session-timeout>
   </session-config>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <!--Error handling-->
   <error-page>
      <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
      <location>/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true</location>
   </error-page>
   <error-page>
       <error-code>403</error-code>
       <location>/error/loginerror.xhtml</location>
   </error-page>
   <error-page>
       <error-code>404</error-code>
       <location>/error/error404.xhtml</location>
   </error-page>
   <!--Security-->
    <login-config>
      <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
      <realm-name>jdbc-realm</realm-name>
      <form-login-config>
          <form-login-page>/index.xhtml</form-login-page>
          <form-error-page>/error/loginerror.xhtml</form-error-page>
      </form-login-config>
   </login-config>
   <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>Admin user</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/secured/admin/*</url-pattern>
          <http-method>GET</http-method>
          <http-method>POST</http-method>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
      <user-data-constraint>
          <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
   <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Root Secured</web-resource-name>
          <description>Root folder</description>
          <url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>
          <http-method>GET</http-method>
          <http-method>POST</http-method>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
          <role-name>CLIENT</role-name>
          <role-name>MANAGER</role-name>
          <role-name>TECH</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
      <user-data-constraint>
          <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
   <security-constraint> 
      <web-resource-collection> 
          <web-resource-name>All Pages</web-resource-name> 
          <url-pattern>/error/*</url-pattern> 
          <http-method>POST</http-method> 
          <http-method>GET</http-method> 
      </web-resource-collection> 
      <auth-constraint> 
          <role-name>PUBLIC</role-name> 
      </auth-constraint> 
   </security-constraint>
   <security-role>
      <description>Administrador</description>
      <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
   </security-role>
   <security-role>
      <description>Clientes</description>
      <role-name>CLIENT</role-name>
   </security-role>
   <security-role>
      <description>Gerente de Projetos</description>
      <role-name>MANAGER</role-name>
   </security-role>
   <security-role>
      <description>Tecnico de Campo</description>
      <role-name>TECH</role-name>
   </security-role>
</web-app>
```

I have know idea How to fix that and I have hint that the login configuration and the error page configuration for ViewExpiredException have some to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I belive I found the problem, Can't explain why, but as soon as I changed the url-pattern from:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
```

To:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It started working again. That's a shame. I didn't want the to have this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If session is expired and you get viewexpiredexception, I believe you want to go to login.xhtml and not to index.xhtml again.. Right.. ? In your web.xml you are configuring to index.xhtml. (which i think is not the login page.. )

Comment: My login page is the index.xhtml. That part is configured right.