# What is the correct method of cache - control in python webpy framework

Tags: python, browser, header, cache-control, web.py

I am trying to build a website in python webpy framework and I am having trouble in cache-control of web browser. When the user presses the back button of the browser it goes back to the userpage even though the user has logged out.

My code looks like this -  it has errors but I am not sure how it is done

```
class Logout:
    web.header("Cache-Control",
           "no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store")
    def GET(self):
        session.login=0
        session.kill()
        raise web.seeother('/')
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
I am actually looking for the python code because I have no idea where that "web.header" is to be placed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid back button on JSF web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsf-web-application)

Comment: If you know python can you please tell me where am I going wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your web.header directives inside the actual GET and SET methods on the classes.

So your case would be:

```
class Logout:

    def GET(self):
        web.header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store")
        session.login=0
        session.kill()
        raise web.seeother('/')
```