# Unable to disable webpage caching in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, caching

I have a form with some fields, like `<p:inputText>` and `<p:selectOneMenu>`, I am trying to prevent the user from navigating back to a previous page, without clearing the form fields or request a new page, 
referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsf-web-application) SO question, i tried to implement the filter:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        //if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
            res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            res.setHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
        //} removed the condition, to double check

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

I have even added `autocomplete="off"` to the fields and added the meta data in  the page:

But every time the presses the forward/back button, he gets the old form (with the old values) back.
It works on firefox, but not on google chrome.
Am i missing something?

Comment: What form exactly is it? Is it a login form with a password field?

Comment: No, simple form with some select menu and input fields