# JSF page content not being updated

Tags: jsf, caching

I have a JSF application in wich i'm using `ui:composition`/`ui:include` to display some elements inside a page like in the following code

template.xhtml

```
...
<h:body>
  ...
  <h:panelGroup id="mainPanel">
    <ui:include src="#{myBean.page}"/>
  </h:panelGroup>
  ...
</h:body>
```

items-list.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
  ...
    <h:form>
      <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{myBean.items}">
        <p:column>
          <h:commandLink action="#{myBean.loadItemDetail(item)}"
            process="@this"
            update="mainPanel">
            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
          </h:commandLink>
        </p:column>
      </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
  ...
</ui:composition>
```

items-detail.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
  <h:form>
    <!-- Some code to display and modify the item details-->
  </h:form>
<ui:composition>
```

MyBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {
  private String page;
  private List<Item> items;
  private ItemDetail itmDetail;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    page = "items-list.xhtml"
    items = ... //some logic to populate the items list
  }

  public void loadItemDetail(Item item){
    itmDetail = ... //some logic to get the item's detail
    page = "item-detail.xhtml"
  }
}
```

The first time I click on an item to see the details it works fine but after that, if I click on the browser's back button and try to load a different item details it keeps showing me the details of the first item.

I check the JSF lifeCycle for each call and although in every call the application goes through all the satages, only the first one calls the bean method `locadItemDetail`. is there a reason why my method is being ignored after the first success call? is there some kind of cache on JSF where my data is bean taken from instead of my Bean?

Also i tried to avoid this behavior implementing a filter as is suggest in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsf-web-application) and it kind of works but now when I click browser's back button it show me an annoying page preventing me from resend the form; is there a way to prevent that?

**Note:**
I know that i could change the app to use GET method instead of  POST to avoid this cache problem but it will required some serious changes over the app so that's not an option.

Any help or guidance about why could this be happening will be appreciated.