# Preventing ViewExpiredException with JSF 2 after redeploy

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a problem where every time I redeploy my app, any existing sessions are broken and the requests result in a `ViewExpiredException`.  None of the advice in related questions or outside mailing list / forum posts seems to fix this issue.  I can redeploy the same WAR file completely unchanged and the behavior is the same.

I'm using Apache MyFaces 2.2.0, Tomcat 7.0.56 and Primefaces 5.0.

The message of the exception is `No saved view state could be found for the view identifier:` with whatever page would be requested.  Primefaces' `menubar` is used for navigation, which seems to be implemented as a `<form>` with POST requests.  These messages occur both with those navigation options and other AJAX that uses POST.

I have tried:

1. Setting explicit `org.apache.myfaces.SECRET` and `org.apache.myfaces.MAC_SECRET` values, as seen [in this document](https://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Secure_Your_Application).
2. Both `client` and `server` values for the `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` parameter.
3. Ensuring all beans and their transitive fields are serializable. No serialization errors are reported in the logs.
4. Using a filter to add no-cache headers, e.g. as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2114115/1464861).
5. Session persistence is not disabled, that is my `context.xml` has `<Manager pathname="" />` commented out.

Comment: Have you set up org.apache.myfaces.MAC_SECRET param? The info stored in the view state is both encrypted and tampered, and a new key for both is generated every time the app is restarted. See [Security configuration for Myfaces Core](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Secure_Your_Application)

Comment: Tried it, didn't help.  I edited the question to reflect this and give additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that losing sessions is a "feature" of Tomcat since at least version 6 and continuing to version 7 when deploying via WAR file.  We have to copy an unpacked directory to avoid losing the sessions, because WAR changes cause an `undeploy` followed by a `deploy`, as opposed to a `reload`.

This [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46924) states:

> There are ways to achieve an update to an application without dropping the sessions. The simplest is probably:
>   - deploy as an exploded directory rather than a WAR
>   - update the files
>   - touch web.xml to trigger a reload
>
> The reason for the current behaviour is to prevent problems when WARs are updated in incompatible ways and anything other than a full undeploy followed by (essentially) a new deployment causes conflicts.

This is still the case in the [current Tomcat 7.0 documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html):

> Currently, application reloading (to pick up changes to the classes or web.xml file) is not supported when a web application is deployed directly from a WAR file. It only works when the web application is deployed from an unpacked directory.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager" saveOnRestart="true"/>
```

Comment: Tried it but it did not make a difference.  According to the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts) the standard Manager already has this behavior.

Comment: double check that it is commented out (or explicited) also in `tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/appname.xml`; sometimes tomcat retains context files on redeploy. Also check if tomcat creates `tomcat/temp/sessions.ser` or `${java.io.tmpdir}/sessions.ser` file and that those folders have write access.

Comment: The file gets created if I shutdown Tomcat.  In fact, the sessions survive a Tomcat restart just fine.  But they do not survive a re-deploy, e.g. if I just `touch myapp.war`.  Maybe the difference is that I see an "Undeploying context" message in the latter case but not when I restart Tomcat?