# It is wrong to ignore ViewExpiredException?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, viewexpiredexception

A week ago, I have studied about ViewExpiredException, and I've read several things about it.

- [viewExpiredException JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114010/viewexpiredexception-jsf)
- [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)
- [Session timeout and ViewExpiredException handling on JSF/PrimeFaces ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203195/session-timeout-and-viewexpiredexception-handling-on-jsf-primefaces-ajax-request)

My problem, which is some cases, I would like to ignore the `ViewExpiredException`. These are situations that do not need a "session", and my Beans are `@RequestScoped`. As an example, the pages `login.xhtml`, `register.xhtml` and `passwordRecovery.xhtml`.

In these cases, it is very strange display an error to the user saying that your session has expired. So if you open the login page and stand still for a while, when he inform your data and click Login, it would be forwarded to an error page. I would just ignore it and let transparent to the user.

So, my solution so far is create a `ExceptionHandler` to ignore these exceptions:

```
@Override
public void handle() throws FacesException {
    for (Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> i = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        ExceptionQueuedEvent event = i.next();
        ExceptionQueuedEventContext context = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();
        Throwable t = context.getException();
        // just remove the exception from queue
        if (t instanceof ViewExpiredException) {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
    getWrapped().handle();
}
```

Then, I created a filter to check whether the user is logged in, if not then redirected to login page (*This filter applies only pages that require authentication*):

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    if (!loginManagedBean.isLogged()) {
        String pathLogin = request.getContextPath() + "/" + LOGIN_VIEW;
        if (isAJAXRequest(request)) {
            response.setContentType("text/xml");
            response.getWriter()
                    .append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
                    .printf("<partial-response><redirect url=\"%s\"></redirect></partial-response>", pathLogin);
            return;
        }

        pathLogin += "?source=" + request.getServletPath();

        response.sendRedirect(pathLogin);
        return;
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

So when the session expires, does not affect the user experience in the login and registration pages. And on pages I wish session, are handled by the filter.

That would be a good solution? Are there any security risk to ignore `ViewExpiredException` in a `ExceptionHandler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring them is not technically bad in this specific case, but it indicates a bad design. It's as if you're using the wrong tool for the job. I.e. those views should actually never expire.

Just make specifically those views stateless.

```xml
<f:view transient="true">
    ...
</f:view>
```

This can be placed anywhere in the page, even duplicated, but most self-documenting is making it the top level tag of the page, composition or definition.

#### See also:

- [What is the usefulness of statelessness in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890995/what-is-the-usefulness-of-statelessness-in-jsf)

Comment: Thanks for answering. In this case, it is recommended to put `transient="true" `in the  `<h:body>' on the login page.

Comment: No, on the `<f:view>` exactly as answered. Putting it on other components will only make the particular components stateless, not the view itself.

Comment: Ok, so I must put the `<f:view>` on my page, and put the `<h:form>` login into it?

Comment: Yes, it can be placed anywhere in the view. Most self-documenting is making it the top level tag.

Comment: Interesting. Again, thank you for dedicating to the community. Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82699/discussion-between-douglas-junior-and-balusc).